# \AtBeginDocument and packages

Tags: package-writing, lthooks, atbegindocument

Here is a very puzzling behaviour of the (Lua)LaTeX compiler. In the situation below, the output depends on whether some code in put in a package or directly in the main file; asking for an extra `\relax` command at the beginning of the document changes the behaviour; and I do not manage to pin the source of some mysterious bug... I would like to understand what happens under the hood of the compiler to produce such a behaviour, in order to avoid similar undesired behaviours in the sequel!

The situation is the following. Let the following document `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{sandbox}
\begin{document}
$\alpha$
\end{document}
```

together with the following `sandbox.sty` file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{sandbox}
\AtBeginDocument{\relax}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\alpha{\beta}}
\endinput
```

After compiling, it prints some alpha symbol, while it should have printed some beta...! This is the first surprising behaviour.

Even more mysterious, if I do *either* of the follwing three:

- Commenting the line `\AtBeginDocument{\relax}` in `sandbox.sty`;
- Commenting the line `\RequirePackage{unicode-math}` in `sandbox.sty`;
- Replacing the line `\usepackage{sandbox}` in `main.tex` by the core content of `sandbox.sty` (i.e., the three lines being the actual content of the package),

then it prints some beta, as initially expected... That seems completely incoherent! Has anyone a clue for an explanation?...

Comment: It's best to treat this as "undefined behavior" (i.e. never write some code that relies on this behavior), but a guess is that `lthooks` (which provides `\AtBeginDocument`) calls the hook codes sorted **first** by package, **then** by the "normal" order where the package-order is defined by the order the packages first add a hook. (so if you comment out the `\relax` hook code then your package becomes the **second** one to add a hook code after `unicode-math` package)

Comment: side note, questions asking "why this C code is wrong" usually just get answered by "it's undefined behavior", but "technically" TeX has no undefined behavior, just "behavior dependent on how this package is implemented"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in comments, this is to do with the behaviour of adding to hooks. Material is added to hooks and the default ordering is that 'earlier' files get their hook content executed earlier, *except* the top-level entries (The user doc) are last. We can see that if we add `\ShowHook{begindocument}` to the input, which gives:

```latex
-> The hook 'begindocument':
> Code chunks:
>     sandbox -> \relax \renewcommand \alpha {\beta }
>     fontspec-luatex -> \tl_set_eq:NN \cyrillicencoding \g_fontspec_encoding_t
l \tl_set_eq:NN \latinencoding \g_fontspec_encoding_tl \RenewDocumentCommand \o
ldstylenums {m}{\__fontspec_main_oldstylenums:n {##1}}\fontspec_maybe_setup_mat
hs: 
>     amsmath -> \reset@strutbox@ \MakeRobust \dddot \MakeRobust \ddddot \Umath
charnumdef \std@minus \Umathcodenum `\-\relax \Umathcharnumdef \std@equal \Umat
hcodenum `\=\relax \expandafter \let \csname overleftarrow \endcsname \@undefin
ed \expandafter \let \csname overrightarrow \endcsname \@undefined \MakeRobust 
\overrightarrow \MakeRobust \overleftarrow \MakeRobust \overleftrightarrow \Mak
eRobust \underrightarrow \MakeRobust \underleftarrow \MakeRobust \underleftrigh
tarrow 
>     unicode-math-luatex -> \__um_define_math_chars: \tl_if_eq:onT {\g__fontsp
ec_mathrm_tl }{\rmdefault }{\__fontspec_setmathrm_hook:nn {}{}}\tl_if_eq:onT {\
g__fontspec_mathsf_tl }{\sfdefault }{\__fontspec_setmathsf_hook:nn {}{}}\tl_if_
eq:onT {\g__fontspec_mathtt_tl }{\ttdefault }{\__fontspec_setmathtt_hook:nn {}{
}}\bool_if:NF \g__um_main_font_defined_bool \__um_load_lm: \__um_setup_mathtext
: \__um_define_prime_commands: \__um_define_prime_chars: \cs_new_protected:Npn 
\__um_patch_url: {\tl_put_left:Nn \Url@FormatString {\__um_switch_to:n {literal
}}\tl_put_right:Nn \UrlSpecials {\do \`{\mathchar `\`}\do \'{\mathchar `\'}\do 
\${\mathchar `\$}\do \&{\mathchar `\&}}}\@ifpackageloaded {url}{\__um_patch_url
: }{}\cs_new_protected:Npn \__um_patch_mathtools_B: {\cs_set_eq:NN \MToverbrack
et \overbracket \cs_set_eq:NN \MTunderbracket \underbracket \AtBeginDocument {\
msg_warning:nn {unicode-math}{mathtools-overbracket}\cs_set:Npn \downbracketfil
l ####1####2{\tl_set:Nn \l_MT_bracketheight_fdim {.27ex}\downbracketend {####1}
{####2}\leaders \vrule \@height ####1\@depth \z@ \hfill \downbracketend {####1}
{####2}}\cs_set:Npn \upbracketfill ####1####2{\tl_set:Nn \l_MT_bracketheight_fd
im {.27ex}\upbracketend {####1}{####2}\leaders \vrule \@height \z@ \@depth ####
1\hfill \upbracketend {####1}{####2}}\cs_set_eq:NN \Uoverbracket \overbracket \
cs_set_eq:NN \Uunderbracket \underbracket \cs_set_eq:NN \overbracket \MToverbra
cket \cs_set_eq:NN \underbracket \MTunderbracket }}\@ifpackageloaded {mathtools
}{\__um_patch_mathtools_B: }{}\cs_new_protected:Npn \__um_patch_mathtools_C: {\
msg_warning:nn {unicode-math}{mathtools-colon}\DeclareDocumentCommand \dblcolon
 {}{\Colon }\DeclareDocumentCommand \coloneqq {}{\coloneq }\DeclareDocumentComm
and \Coloneqq {}{\Coloneq }\DeclareDocumentCommand \eqqcolon {}{\eqcolon }}\@if
packageloaded {mathtools}{\__um_patch_mathtools_C: }{}\Umathcharnumdef \std@min
us \Umathcodenum `-\Umathcharnumdef \std@equal \Umathcodenum `=\debug_suspend: 
\__um_resolve_greek: \debug_resume: \@ifpackageloaded {amsmath}{}{\__um_redefin
e_radical: }\__um_setup_active_frac: \g__um_secret_hook_tl 
> Document-level (top-level) code (executed last):
>     ---
> Extra code for next invocation:
>     ---
> Rules:
>     ---
> Execution order:
>     sandbox, fontspec-luatex, amsmath, unicode-math-luatex.
<recently read> }
```

Notice that the hook for `sandbox` will occur before that for `unicode-math`, so the latter will 'win' for re-defining the same entry.

The point of the hook system is to allow control of ordering. So you need only to add

```latex
\DeclareHookRule{begindocument}{sandbox}{after}{unicode-math-luatex}
\DeclareHookRule{begindocument}{sandbox}{after}{unicode-math-xetex}
```

to your `sandbox` file to ensure that the hook code is ordered:

```latex
> Execution order (after applying rules):
>     fontspec-luatex, amsmath, unicode-math-luatex, sandbox.
```

Comment: Many thanks for this perfect explanation! :-D I even more appreciate that you have added an explanation for how to control the ordering, with I had not explicitly asked for, but will be greatly useful to me! 8-)